# why is this udev rule ignored?

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount, ntfs, udev

So I'm using the following rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb-disks.rules` and it's not working. The contents are as follows, what I want to happen is ntfs drives to have posix permissions (multi-user & group ownership and permissions), support UTF8 paths & file names when mounted.

```
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ntfs", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}="ntfs-3g", ENV{mount_options}="%E{mount_options},utf8,permissions"
```

I'm using xenial with all updates. Running `mount -l` returns two entries for the disk; but I haven't found a way to edit the mount rules

```
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdc2 on /media/lewis/drive-label type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2) [drive-label]
```